# How to Get the Default Language Row From a Table which has rows for each language?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Let say I have these 2 tables and I ahve 2 languages, en and ar,

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[xProduct](
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Model] [varchar](255) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_xProduct] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[xProductT](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [PID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Lang] [varchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [IsDefault] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_xProductT] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]



-- xProduct
ID  Model
1   SVE11611
2   SVE11711

-- xProductT
ID  PID Lang       Name                        Description         IsDefault
1   1   EN  Sony Vaio E11611    Sony Vaio E11611 Description         1
2   1   AR  سوني فايو E11611    وصف سوني فايو E11611              NULL
3   2   EN  Sony Vaio E11711    Sony Vaio E11711 Description        1
```

Here is what I have tried,

```
declare @lang varchar(2) ='en'
declare @id int =1
-- Works and give a single row
Select p.*,pt.* from xProduct p inner join xProductT pt on (p.id = pt.pid and pt.lang = @lang)where p.id=@id    

set @lang  ='ar'
set  @id =1    
-- Works and give a single row
Select p.*,pt.* from xProduct p inner join xProductT pt on (p.id = pt.pid and pt.lang = @lang)where p.id=@id

set @lang  ='en'
set  @id =2    
-- Works and give a single row
Select p.*,pt.* from xProduct p inner join xProductT pt on (p.id = pt.pid and pt.lang = @lang)where p.id=@id

set @lang  ='ar'
set  @id =2    
-- Does not work I need to select the default one
Select p.*,pt.* from xProduct p inner join xProductT pt on (p.id = pt.pid and pt.lang = @lang)where p.id=@id
```

But the 4th one not working?

Comment: I'd normally recommend storing the default language values "in-row" (in this case, in the `xProduct` table). That way, you can ensure that they exist, and it's easy to fall back to the default (using a `LEFT JOIN` to the translation table and a `COALESCE`)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, is it not possible with above schema

Comment: @user960567 - The suggestion was to change the schema.

Comment: @MartinSmith, can provide me answer with new schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally have to join to the translation table twice if the defaults are being stored there:

```
set @lang  ='ar'
set  @id =2    
-- Does not work I need to select the default one
Select
    p.*,COALESCE(pt.Name,ptDef.Name) as Name
from
    xProduct p
       left join
    xProductT pt
       on
         (p.id = pt.pid and pt.lang = @lang)
       inner join
    xProductT ptDef
       on
         (p.id = ptDef.pid and ptDef.IsDefault=1)
where p.id=@id
```

The `COALESCE` returns the first non-NULL argument - so this causes it to prefer values from the `pt` row, if the join succeeds, or from `ptDef` is the first join fails.

---

As I indicated in my comment, I'd normally recommend this schema instead:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[xProduct](
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Model] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [DefaultName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [DefaultDescription] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_xProduct] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[xProductT](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [PID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Lang] [varchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_xProductT] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Because you can now guarantee that a default language version has been provided (and don't need to add constraints to the translation table to prevent multiple languages being marked as the default). It then simplifies the query:

```
 set @lang  ='ar'
set  @id =2    
-- Does not work I need to select the default one
Select
    p.*,COALESCE(pt.Name,p.DefaultName) as Name
from
    xProduct p
       left join
    xProductT pt
       on
         (p.id = pt.pid and pt.lang = @lang)
where p.id=@id
```

(You can, if you want to go overboard with this, store which language the defaults are in and *prevent* a translation for this language from appearing in the translations table. This is usually overboard though - usually, all of the defaults are in a single language anyway.

Comment: What If I have 3 languages then I need another join?

Comment: @user960567 - no, the first join is to the language that you're hoping to obtain a translation for (It's the same as your original one, relying on `@lang`, but it needs to be a `left join` rather than an `inner join`, because we want it to be able to fail). The second join is to the default language.

Comment: I need to use the COALESCE fro all fields on xProductT

Answer (score 0):

you dont have value in the table **xProductT**

```
for @lang  ='ar' and @id =2
```

try something like this:

```
set @lang  ='ar'
set  @id =2    
-- Does not work I need to select the default one
Select p.*,
       isnull([PID],1),
       isnull([Lang],'EN'),
       isnull([Name],'Sony Vaio E11611'),
       isnull([Description],'Sony Vaio E11611 Description'),
       isnull([IsDefault],1)

from xProduct p left join xProductT pt on (p.id = pt.pid and pt.lang = @lang)where p.id=@id
```

#### [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aaafe/2)

Comment: Yes, I want to select 'en' in this case

Comment: you can, as long as your default value doesn't change.. If the default value changes, then you will have to re-write the code